# Match each comma separated string in R dataframe with values in another df

Tags: r, dataframe

Problem: I need to match comma separated strings in one data frame with another that has some values. My final dataframe should place the highest those values in the first dataframe. I have showed that as an example. I'm new to R and I'm unable to find logic to build this code. I'd appreciate if I can get some help in getting started.

Two DFs

```
DF1: 
Fruits
Guava
Mango, apple, banana
Apricot, plum
Avocado, Cherry, blueberry, raspberry

DF2:

Fruits Price   
Guava    10 
Mango    30 
Apple    25 
Banana   15              
Apricot  40  
Plum     35   
Avocado  120   
Cherry   23    
Blueberry 200 
Raspberry 125
```

Output DF3 : Should create a new column "highest price" and place the highest price across the group of fruits in DF1

```
DF3: 
Fruits Highest Price
Guava    10
Mango, apple, banana 30
Apricot, plum  40
Avocado, Cherry, blueberry, raspberry 200
```

Comment: It might be easier to turn everything into a non comma separated file first.

Comment: Check for the **regular expression** (regex) tools. They're powerful and could help you. For instance, I would try `grepl()` function: check it with `?grepl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
DF1$`Highest price` = sapply(tolower(DF1$Fruits), 
       function(x){ max(DF2$Price[which(tolower(DF2$Fruits)%in%strsplit(x,", ")[[1]])])})

> DF1
                                 Fruits Highest price
1                                 Guava            10
2                  Mango, apple, banana            30
3                         Apricot, plum            40
4 Avocado, Cherry, blueberry, raspberry           200
```

A shorter alternative, as proposed by Ronak Shah

```
sapply(strsplit(df1$Fruits, ","), function(x) max(df2$Price[tolower(df2$Fruits) %in% tolower(x)]))
```

Comment: You are totally right, I will append it to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

An idea using `library(tidyverse)` could be to separate to long format, merge and summarise to take the maximum, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
 mutate(Fruits = tolower(Fruits), ID = row_number()) %>% 
 separate_rows(Fruits, sep = ',') %>% 
 left_join(df2 %>% mutate(Fruits = tolower(Fruits)), by = 'Fruits') %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 summarise(Fruits = toString(Fruits), Price = max(Price))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 3
>      ID Fruits                                Price
>   <int> <chr>                                 <dbl>
> 1     1 guava                                    10
> 2     2 mango, apple, banana                     30
> 3     3 apricot, plum                            40
> 4     4 avocado, cherry, blueberry, raspberry   200
> ```